# When NOT to use NoSQL?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

There was an article on [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/) a couple of days ago that reached first page titled something like
 **"2 cases when not to use Mongodb"** but I really can't find it anymore...

1. Does anyone know where I can find the above described article?
2. What cases are there when NoSQL fails?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448194/mongodb-vs-mysql/4448292

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> We use MongoDB for storing tons and tons of analytics data for which we don't care if some stuff occasionally gets lost in a server crash. The data really fits MongoDB well and it would have been a nightmare if we were to use an SQL database for this. But for bank transactions we wouldn't even consider MongoDB.
>   The write lock might be a problem for some people. On the other hand MongoDB supports easy sharding, much easier than with SQL. Sharding allows us to scale horizontally which is a huge plus for our data.

1. http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1691748

Comment: Nice find, but the actual article appears to be here: http://ethangunderson.com/blog/two-reasons-to-not-use-mongodb/

Comment: 2 b fair, OP did schu it in Q. :)

Answer (score 0):

By any reasonable definition "NoSQL" ought to include non-SQL RDBMSs in its scope (because there's no sound reason why the relational model can't address the same requirements as other NoSQL models). If you accept that, then there is no limit to what NoSQL DBMSs could do. We would have no more need of SQL - ever!

Sadly, there seems to be a common assumption among NoSQL thought leaders that "NoSQL" has to mean "not relational". That is highly unfortunate because if the relational model is ignored then NoSQL is never likely to replace SQL for many purposes. (I take it for granted that finding a long-term, *relational* model replacement for SQL would actually be a good thing :)

Comment: Typical hate mongering against SQL

Comment: I don't hate SQL but I do try to keep an open mind about better alternatives to what is after all a 30 year-old language and paradigm with some highly inconvenient defects.

Comment: Could you add some link to a relational NoSQL DBs you like? I've found some, but nothing was really exciting, but maybe you can point me to more interesting stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use NoSQL typically when you....

... don't want to use SQL! */hardy har har*

Most of the NoSQL solutions I've seen seem to fall in the key-value store approach, and aren't relational. They tend to give up ACID properties.

So when you evaluate a database system, when you *don't* need ACID, when you *don't* want relational algebra, when you *do* have a need for a KV store, then the NoSQL approach is your friend.

Note too that there is a wide variety of 'NoSQL' systems, and they all are busily working on slightly different approaches.

Comment: Why do you think `NoSQL` implies no `ACID`? I personally have built an app on top of `BerkeleyDB` (which is not relational) with full transaction support.

Comment: @Quassnoi: because no ACID is one of the common tendencies of NoSQL.