# MongoDB or MySQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb, nosql

I am working on a website which would be having all the restaurant related details for a particular country. I was considering which DB would be best suitable for this kind of scenario,very similar to [this](https://www.zomato.com/).

I was considering to use MongoDB just because it would provide me with flexible schema and Simple queries for data retrieval. I am rethinking over my decision as neither my data is going to be too large as of my now so there wont be nay blockage for me w.r.t data size in MySQL.

What would be best way to choose between the 2.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448194/mongodb-vs-mysql

Comment: [Mysql vs Mongodb 1000 reads] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702643/mysql-vs-mongodb-1000-reads)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends truly on whether you want data integrity and ACID features of a Relational Database. If a Relational Database is built correctly using the Relational Model and E.F Codd's rules, you will never have a problem with having duplicate data, inconsistencies, and other maladies.(This is assuming you use a RDBMS that is worth its salt, like oracle or SAP ASE)

However, you also have the option of MongoDB, which as you pointed out, is very flexible. However, through my experience, you will have to do a lot more manual work ensuring data accuracy and integrity.

However, certain things are easier in it, and it is by no means not successful. I use Mongo as a data back end for simulation servers I run, and it performs beautifully. Where mongo truly exceeds is with its atomic documents, and that's where Mongo pulled ahead of other NoSQL systems like CouchDB.

What it truly comes down to is what *kind* of data you are storing. If you are storing relational data, use a RDBMS. If it is more document based, use Mongo or a similar data storage engine. I do not like the idea of choosing a data storage engine by what is popular or what is new. Use what fits your data.

I hope this answers you question satisfactorily, if not please comment below.

Comment: Thanks for the response  @Reliant, yeah the answer was quite helpful for me to decide one amongst them. Probably i might go with MySQL as my data is slightly inclined towards being relational, which i would be giving priority over the flexibility i would achieve using MongoDB.